# What programs can display an RTFD (rich text + attachments) document?

Tags: file-format

Nothing on my Ubuntu 11 system seems to automatically open rtfd files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is a mac file and it can't be opened in Linux.

See also in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format_Directory#Linux).

> In contrast to RTF, RTFD files cannot be opened properly by applications on non-Mac OS X operating systems, as bundles are currently only supported on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

While there might not be any GNU/Linux applications that *support* `.rtfd` files, the `d` in `.rtfd` stands for *directory*. That is, this is actually a *folder*, and you can look inside it to see the constituent files which provide the document's content. This will often make it possible to access the document.

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFD) for more information about the RTFD format.

Also, that article suggests that Ink.app, and possibly other GNUstep programs, can open RTFD files; it should be possible to install that in Ubuntu, though I don't think there's any official Ubuntu package that provides it.